# One digit inputs results into 2 digits output assembly

Tags: assembly

The assignment is to get onedigit input from users and output 1-2 digits. I don't know why it would not work 1digit + 1digit =1 digit and why sometimes it works on 1digit + 1digit = 2 digits but sometimes it won't . It also includes the subtract, multiply, divide and modulo operations.

TITLE

```
;-----------------------------------------------------

.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64
.DATA

INPUT DB 13, 10, "Enter input : ","$"
SUM DB 13,10, "The sum is : ","$"
DIFF DB 13,10, "The difference is : ","$"
MULTI DB 13,10, "The product is : ","$"
DIVI DB 13,10, "The quotient is : ","$"
MODULO DB 13,10, "The modulo is : ","$"
NUM1 db ?
NUM2 db ?
OP db ?
RES db ?

;-----------------------------------------------------

.CODE
MAIN PROC NEAR

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

; outputs "input" message
LEA DX, INPUT
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h

; get first input
MOV AH, 01h
INT 21h
SUB AL, '0'
MOV NUM1, AL

; get operand
MOV AH, 01h
INT 21h
MOV OP, AL

; get second input
MOV AH, 01h
INT 21h
SUB AL, '0'
MOV NUM2, AL

CMP OP, "+"
JE @ADD

CMP OP, "-"
JE @SUB

CMP OP, "*"
JE @MULTIPLY

CMP OP, "/"
JE @DIVIDE

CMP OP, "%"
JE @MOD

@ADD :
ADD AL, NUM1
MOV RES, AL

LEA DX, SUM
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@SUB :
MOV AL, NUM1
CMP AL, NUM2
JG @WITHOUTNEG
JMP @WITHNEG

@WITHNEG :
MOV AL, NUM2
SUB AL, NUM1
MOV RES, AL

LEA DX, DIFF
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h

MOV OP, "-"
MOV DL, OP
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@WITHOUTNEG :
MOV AL, NUM1
SUB AL, NUM2
MOV RES, AL

LEA DX, DIFF
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@MULTIPLY :
MOV AL, NUM1
IMUL NUM2
MOV RES, AL

LEA DX, MULTI
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@DIVIDE :
XOR AX, AX
MOV AL, NUM1
IDIV NUM2
MOV RES, AL

LEA DX, DIVI
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@MOD :
XOR AX, AX
MOV AL, NUM1
IDIV NUM2
MOV RES, AH

LEA DX, MODULO
MOV AH, 09h
INT 21h
JMP @PRINT

@PRINT :
XOR AX, AX

MOV AL, RES
MOV BL, 10
IDIV BL

ADD AL, '0'
MOV DL, AL
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h

ADD AH, '0'
MOV DL, AH
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h
JMP @EXIT

@EXIT :
MOV AH,4Ch
INT 21h

MAIN ENDP

;----------------------------------------------------------------

END MAIN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `MOV AH,02h`
>   `INT 21h`
>   
>   `ADD AH, '0'`

You're overwriting the remainder with the WRITE CHARACTER function number here. You need to save and restore `AH`, e.g. like this:

```
MOV DL, AL
PUSH AX   ; Save AX on the stack
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h
POP AX    ; Restore AX

ADD AH, '0'
```

Comment: wow I would have never figured that one out!!! Thank you so much! :) This happened a few times and i guess it's because i always overwrite the remainder thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In your "print" procedure you are modifying AH and then trying to use that value later.

```
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h

ADD AH, '0'
```

You must preserve your value before modifying the register, the PUSH and POP instruction will help you.

```
PUSH AX
MOV AH,02h
INT 21h

POP AX
ADD AH, '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

here.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

first db 13,10, 'Enter 1st number: $'
second db 13, 10, 'Enter 2nd number: $'
result db 13,10, 'Result: $'
invalid db 13,10, 'Invalid number!!! $'

.code

start:
    mov ax,03
    int 10h

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

mn:
    mov dx, offset first
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov cl, al
    cmp al, 30h
    jl nvalid
    cmp al, 39h
    jg nvalid
    jmp proceed

nvalid:
    mov dx, offset invalid
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    jmp mn

proceed:
    sub cl, 30h
    mov dx, offset second
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    cmp al, 30h
    jl nvalid
    cmp al, 39h
    jg nvalid
    sub al, 30h

    xor ah,ah
    add al, cl
    aaa

    mov cx, ax
    add cx, 3030h
    mov dx, offset result
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, ch
    int 21h

    mov dl, cl
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

end start
```